# Calling all functions in an object/function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop

I'm trying to do a little bit of OOP in JavaScript and I'm trying to set something up dynamically so that I can call all functions in a given object or function.

I have a loop that every second calls a function, but at certain times that function is going to need to do different things. So I was thinking I'd call the function every second and then add extra functions to that using the 'prototype' property.

Basically there's this endless loop that constantly calls a function and depending upon user interaction at the moment that function is called it may need to execute different functions.

```
var MAIN = function() {
var self = this;

this.Tick = 1;
this.Timer = function(){};

this.StartTimer = function(loop, interval) {
    self.Timer = setInterval(loop, interval);
}

this.StopTimer = function() {
    clearInterval(self.Timer);  
    self.Tick = 1;
}

this.Loop = function() {
    console.log(self.Tick);

    switch (self.Tick) {
        case 2:
            self.Phase1.init();
            break;
        case 4: 
            self.Phase2();
            break;
        case 6:
            self.Phase3();
            break;
        case 8:
            self.Phase4();
            break;
        case 10:
            self.Tick = 0;
            break;
    }

    self.Tick++;    
}       

this.Phase1 = function() {

}
```

I've tried two methods of listing functions in Phase1. I've tried using a function and an object, but the closest I've come to executing the list of functions inside that is listing the name of each function.

### Function Attempt

```
    this.Phase1 = function() {
this.Phase1.Test1 = function() {
        alert("Test1"); 
    };

    this.Phase1.Test2 = function() {
        alert("Test2");
    };
}
```

### Object Attempt

```
this.Phase1 = {
    Test1: function() {
        alert("Test1"); 
    },
    Test2: function() {
        alert("Test2");
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to get a dynamic list of functions that are called every second.

I have no problem calling the function manually. I know that I can use

```
MAIN.Phase1.Test1();
```

But I want to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
var obj = new Phase1();
var tick = 1;

obj[tick]();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Phase1 = {
  Test1: function() {
    alert('test 1');
  },
  Test2: function() {
    alert('test 2');
  },
  Test3: function() {
    alert('test 3');
  }
};

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var testNumber = document.querySelector('input').value; // 1, 2 or 3
  Phase1['Test' + testNumber]();
};
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="3">
<button>run test</button>
```